# GML: Is there an easy way to see the output of a line of code?

Tags: gml

I've been struggling with some code lately (see: [Why are my bullets flying in weird directions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59385400/why-are-my-bullets-flying-in-weird-directions)), and I've begun to suspect that I've I've made an error in my math or the GML functions Sin and Cos have some issues. To make sure myself, I want to run them individually with controlled inputs. If this were python, I'd boot up a python console and enter something along the lines of "sin(pi)" and check the result. Is there any parallel in GML?

Answer (score 2):

I once made [a tool](https://yal.cc/r/gml/) that can compile snippets of GML for quick tests.
An offline version is bundled with GMEdit.

If you'd like to make a REPL kind of thing, there are a few options:

- `execute_string` in [execute_string replica](https://github.com/gamemakerdiscord/execute_string) (mostly complete syntax? Haven't played around with it much)
- `NSP_execute_string` in [NSP2](https://forum.yoyogames.com/index.php?threads/free-nsp-2-a-gml-string-interpreter.551/) (good coverage, but crashes easily)
- `txr_exec` in [TXR](https://yellowafterlife.itch.io/gamemaker-txr) (by me; smaller coverage, but clean code and comes with tutorial on implementation)
- `live_execute_string` in [GMLive.gml](https://yellowafterlife.itch.io/gamemaker-live) (also by me; paid, but covers entirety of syntax)